How do i get a discord.js bot to reply to an interaction based on what options are selected
I want my discord bot to reply to the interaction based on what options are selected for example say i have a command called favourite pet depending on what option the user choose say the options where dog and cat if the user choose dog the bot would reply with 'my favourite pet is dog too' or say the user choose cat the bot would reply with 'my favourite animal is cat too' I cant manage to figure out how to do that
if (interaction.commandName === 'favourite-pet') {
    if (interaction.options === 'dog') {
      interaction.reply(`My favourtie pet is also a dog `)
    }
if (interaction.options === 'cat') {
      interaction.reply(`my favourite animal is also a cat  `)
    }
  }


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use the interaction.options.getString() method.
getString(name: string, required: Boolean)

If “favourite-pet” is the name of your option, here is the completed statement:
if (interaction.options.getString("favourite-pet") === 'dog') {
      interaction.reply(`My favourtie pet is also a dog `)
    }
else if (interaction.options.getString("favourite-pet") === 'cat') {
      interaction.reply(`my favourite animal is also a cat  `)
    }


wow honestly thanks so much bro i have been stuck on that for such a long time your a life saver props to you man cheers
